# Javascript - How do you call a function inside a class from within that class?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call the function MyMethod from within a object but none of the syntax below works.
There must be a really obvious error below but I can't see it.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

   <script type="text/jscript">

     function MyObject() {

       //how do I get one of these to work??
       this.MyMethod; //does not work
       this.MyMethod(); //does not work either
       MyMethod(); //does not work either

       this.MyMethod = function () {
         alert('It works');
       }
     }

     var test = new MyObject();

   </script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you move this part of your code "this.MyMethod = function () { 
         alert('It works'); " above the method calls to MyMethod? and see if that makes a difference?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are two main problems

1. The MIME type is `text/javascript`, not `text/jscript`
2. You are defining the method **after** you try to call it

So:

```
  function MyObject() {
    this.MyMethod = function () {
      alert('It works');
    }
    this.MyMethod(); //should now work
  }

  var test = new MyObject();
```

Answer (score 3):

you have put the call to the private method inside the constructor of the javascript class.
in that point the functions are not yet initialized

but if you initialize the object like so:

```
var test = new MyObject();
```

and then do this:

```
test.myMethod();
```

it will work.

Answer (score 3):

## The 2 ways of defining a function provide different accessibilities

First, setting it a property of the parent function, as is done in the "A" version of your script below. If you do this, the function is only usable **after** you give the definition.

Second, defining the function with the classical approach of "function *functionName* () { ... }". This definition undergoes "hoisting", which means the function becomes available throughout the parent object, i.e. even above the place it is defined. You can see this in the "B" version in the sample below, based on the original poster's code. Also on https://jsfiddle.net/dnL4j30u/

```
<script>
  function MyObject() {

    MyMethod(); 

    this.MyMethod = function() {
      console.log('It works A');
    }

    this.MyMethod(); 

    MyMethod(); 

    function MyMethod() {
      console.log('It works B');
    }

  }
  var test = new MyObject();
</script>
```

The output is

```
 It works B       (this works because the second definition gets hoisted)
 It works A
 It works B
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var MyObject = function MyObject() {
       this.MyMethod = function () {
         alert('It works');
       } }

var test = new MyObject(); test.MyMethod();
```

The above will do. Or you can just create a constructor and call this method inside that. So at the time of object creation it will call this.MyMethod()

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to javaScript but i'd like to contribute to this question. One way is to make object of the class and access to the within function through the object class.

```
      class SomeClass{
          someFunction(input){
                return "Hello " + input
           }
        }
console.log(new SomeClass().someFunction("Mahdi"))
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm pretty sure you can define methods anywhere in the file, even after you call them, but they way you are defining the method is the flaw.

http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#5

Notice that if you define a variable with an anonymous function as it's value then you are not able to call the function by name (because it doesn't have one).  Instead you should name it using the convention

```
function nameOfTheFunction( arguments ) {
...
}
```

I found the following link will to be very useful:

http://www.dustindiaz.com/javascript-function-declaration-ambiguity/

Comment: The flaw is not the way the method is defined, the flaw is when the method is defined.