# calling functions from within a class javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call a function from within a class that is created outside of the class,but when I do JavaScript 'thinks' I am trying to write a new function. In the example below I make a class, I define a function(show), then I try to call a function not in the class(outsideFunction) but when I run my code I get an error

```
function outsideFunction(){
   arc(100,75,50,0,2*Math.PI)
}
class example {
  show(){
    rect(20,20,150,100)
  }
  outsideFunction();                                                           
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - How do you call a function inside a class from within that class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541348/javascript-how-do-you-call-a-function-inside-a-class-from-within-that-class)

Comment: why? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: When do you want `outsideFunction` to run?

Answer (score 1):

You are actually violating objected oriented concept. You can't call a function inside a class. You can call it in a member function like this:

```
function outsideFunction() {
    arc(100, 75, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
}
class example {
    show() {
        rect(20, 20, 150, 100)
    }
    outSideCaller() {
        outsideFunction();
    }
}
```